# Loop over each database and create folders for beach database, and folders for tables within databases, and textfiles for each table header

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I have the following code in a BAT file:

```
::20190330
::JimmyWilliams
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls
Echo Opens up MYSQL and shows databases
pause
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
mysql -uJames -p******* -e "SHOW DATABASES;" > C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\test.txt
pause
```

I want to do three things, and my question is "how do I do these? help please":
1. remove the MYSQL password warning prompt
2. choose which connection/host/server the BAT file should run on (sorry I am not sure what the correct terminology is.)
3.have the have the BAT file:
3a. Create folder for each database
3b. Within each of those folders have a folder for each table
3c. within those table-folders have text files for each table heading.

Comment: You can have files within folders but not folders within files so I am unclear what you are trying to achieve and why you would do this in a bat file rather than use mysql's inbuilt backup.

Comment: I have fixed my original question, I am not using this as a backup. I would like this so I can show people who don't know what databases are, or a boss etc, the overall layout of information without them touching or wrecking anything.

Comment: It seems a good plan to do! Go ahead... (I don't see any question here)

Comment: My question is, how do I do it? I know what I want, this is as far as I have gotten so far.

Comment: Run `help for`, write some code, when you encounter problems, ask questions.  Read [Ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: For #1, [ServerFault...secure...password](https://serverfault.com/questions/476228/whats-a-secure-alternative-to-using-a-mysql-password-on-the-command-line).